# Does "Occur-at-point" already exist?

Tags: search, occur

I wrote an elisp function for myself at the weekend:

```
(defun rr-occur ()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  "Run occur using the `word-at-point'."
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  (let ((term (thing-at-point 'word t)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    (occur term)))
```

This seems such an obvious use-case, I am now wondering if this duplicates a "standard" function.

Comment: Simplify it: (defun rr-occur () (occur (thing-at-point 'word t))). BTW, This has been requested of the emacs developers in the past; maybe try again, maybe this time they'll do it, eg. `C-u M-s o`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of Emacs commands for which `M-n` at the input prompt (`next-history-element`) will insert a reasonable default if there is no next history element available. For `occur` that happens to be the symbol at point.

So this might do what you want: `M-s o M-n`

(You might have to hit `M-n` twice if you have a recent occur search provided as the first 'default').

Answer (score 6):

A common workflow is:

- [start isearch with <kbd>C-s</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Incremental-Search.html), then
- [search for the next word with <kbd>C-w</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Isearch-Yank.html), then
- [run `occur` with the current search string with <kbd>M-s o</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Special-Isearch.html).

Comment: You can also use `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` for the first two steps, so the whole sequence would be: `M-s-. M-s-o`.